# Maximum current capacity of this wire?

Tags: current, wire

I couldn't figure out the maximum amount of continuous current can a 4 meter 0.085 Ohm wire carry? Also, for 300 milliseconds can it handle 100Amps? Provided a powerful fan cooling it?

What about 100A continuous current with a cooling unit(industrial fans)?

Comment: 300ms is duration, what is the duty cycle?  How much voltage drop across the wire can you live with?

Comment: What size (diameter) is the wire?

Comment: Is that 0.085 measured resistance, or 0.085 ohms per foot, per inch, per mile, per kilometer, per square ironing board...?

Comment: Not sure how to calculate the duty cycle haven't worked out the data yet. The diameter of the wire is 1mm, 0.085 is calculated resistance in mm, used the formula R = pL/A converted everything to mm before that.

Comment: That's 0.085 ohms per mm?

Comment: 1mm diameter is roughly 18 AWG - 16A for chassis wiring, 2.2A for power transmission. http://www.powerstream.com/Wire_Size.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If copper wire, that's about an [AWG 18](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_wire_gauge) wire. 100A is above the [fusing current](http://pages.interlog.com/~speff/usefulinfo/fusing.htm) of an AWG 18 copper wire, so without some kind of cooling the copper will actually melt with 100A continuous.

300ms (with sufficient time between pulses for the wire to cool) might be "okay" due to the heat capacity of the wire (you'd have calculate it out) but the wire will get very hot and probably smoke a bit, and perhaps could set things on fire. Any insulation other than something like a quartz tube might be degraded or destroyed, and the wire will tend to oxidize and droop under gravity.

If the wire is other than copper then then answers will be somewhat different, but the approach would be the same.

Comment: Do you know of any conductor that has the potential to surpass copper by major folds? I know of graphene which I heard has the potential to carry 1000x of copper at a much lighter lighter weight.

Comment: @Key: use a superconductor, much lighter and much easier to handle and produce than graphene.

Comment: @Key what are the actual requirements? Why not just use a fatter copper wire?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, your wiki AWG link also lists fusing current for shorter times.  1 sec and 32 ms.  As a "back of the envelope" calculation, I find 1 meter of AWG wire has a volume of ~0.79 cm^3,  heat capacity of copper is about 3.5 J/(K*cm^3) so 2.75 J/K.  and I get 100 A for 1 sec would raise the temp by less than 100 C .(assuming no math mistakes.)  If I use the 1 sec. fusing current I get a temp rise of ~800 C.  That seems reasonable.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Seems reasonable to me, and fits with everyday experience in things like car jumper cables.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany If  I needed to use copper for this application, how much water might I need to transfer all the heat and maintain a continuous 100A to the wire? Would this water need to be cooled as well?

Comment: That's a complex heat transfer question. If you flattened the conductor to a ribbon and cast it inside concrete it might do just fine- the power per linear unit isn't ridiculously high.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany thanks, just to get an idea for "300ms" how much time must it need to cool off? Assuming we had an efficient heat transferring system(which you would recommend concrete)? It might even be shorter than 300ms that is the maximum time frame, wont be continuos since it's risky and the cooling requirements is quite complex.

Comment: You asked a previous question what are my requirements, well to use this exact volume for 100A at a timeframe of 300ms and less. For a repetitive process.